# Simple Tutorial to Create a Scriptable Cocoa Application (Scripting Bridge)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge, cocoa-scripting

Can anyone point me to a really simple *hello world* type of application that introduces ScriptingBridge? Something that takes you step by step to creating a 1 class - 1 method project that can be instantiated from ruby/python/applescript, etc.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what is actually required to create a scriptable cocoa app and haven't been able to find any concrete examples or tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a set of sample codes in ADC!

- [Simple Scripting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScripting/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Simple Scripting: properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScriptingProperties/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Simple Scripting: verbs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScriptingVerbs/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Simple Scripting: objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScriptingObjects/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: +1 to this: I used these myself, really useful. And it turns out it's all quite straightforward, really.